# Dicas para melhorar o desempenho de um site ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aplicação-web, desempenho, asp

Participei do DevDay 2015 e tive a oportunidade de participar da palestra da [Roberta Arcoverde](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/901/rla4) sobre a arquitetura do StackOverflow. Achei interessante a abordagem dela sobre a questão de desempenho, inclusive como ela frisou bem que eles utilizam determinadas técnicas mais rudimentares para manter o site com maior desempenho e eficiência.

Pois bem, recentemente eu criei minha primeira aplicação Web utilizando o ASP.NET MVC e vejo que apesar de utilizar padrões de projeto mais avançados aumentar a extensibilidade e reuso de código, o desempenho apresentado é insatisfatório. Para se ter uma ideia, a página principal da minha aplicação demora uma média de 614 ms.

Esta aplicação é simples, trata-se de uma aplicação para a exibição de informações armazenadas em um banco de dados SQLServer que foram atualizadas por meio de um Webservice por outra aplicação Desktop. Abaixo os recursos utilizados para desenvolver o site:

- EntityFramework (Realizo o mapeamento das classes por meio das classes EntityTypeConfiguration<> ao invés de DataAnnotations).
- Banco SQLServer 2014 com tabelas indexadas.
- Nas views eu utilizo alguns componentes da DevExpress e Twitter Bootstrap para ajustar a responsividade da tela.
- Ainda não implementei cache e nem roteamento na aplicação (espero ter algumas dicas enquanto a isso nesta pergunta)

Apesar de ser um tema amplo, queria saber se tem algumas dicas ou um ponto inicial para me nortear em como melhorar o desempenho da aplicação. Dicas do tipo: como utilizar o cache? é necessário utilizar roteamento? Preciso sair do EntityFramework e migrar para um micro ORM como o Dapper?

Comment: Eu tentaria ver aonde é que está demorando mais, O BANCO ou SITE?

Comment: Sim, com certeza esse é o ponto inicial, estou avaliando possíveis melhorias, mais vou começar avaliando o que eu posso estar fazendo de errado. Valeu PauloHDSousa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Apesar de ser um tema amplo, queria saber se tem algumas dicas ou um ponto inicial para me nortear em como melhorar o desempenho da aplicação.

Tem várias. Vou tentar ser sucinto na resposta, mas acredito que ela ficará um pouco longa.

Não sei se você já reparou, mas na inicialização do projeto, o IIS precisa carregar uma série de Class Libraries para funcionar. É por isto que o tempo da primeira tela é demorado mesmo, e quanto a isto não tem muito o que fazer. Os tempos vão abaixando conforme você vai acessando outras telas.

O que você pode fazer para abaixar este tempo inicial é desinstalar pacotes que você tem plena certeza de que não serão usados na aplicação. Abra o arquivo `packages.config` e veja quais pacotes foram instalados. Depois, abra o Package Manager Console (View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console) e use o seguinte comando para desinstalar:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package NomeDoPacote
```

## Como utilizar o cache?

Há vários tipos de *cache* que podem ser usados no ASP.NET MVC. Um deles é o [Output Cache](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs), que é para o Razor.

Na palestra que você citou, a Roberta disse que o Stack Overflow utiliza quatro níveis de *cache*. Um deles é o [Redis](http://redis.io/), [que tem uma implementação própria feita pelo pessoal da própria equipe do Stack Overflow](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis). Ou seja, tudo o que é acessado vai para a cache e fica lá por pelo menos 24 horas. Isto ajuda muito para, por exemplo, perguntas e respostas recentes. Por isso que a tela parece piscar quando lemos perguntas e respostas que estão no topo da página inicial.

Outra forma de cache é o Elasticsearch (a versão original é em Java, [mas foi portada para .NET](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/_elasticsearch_net.html)), que faz esta seção de links relacionados que temos ao lado.

Um terceiro nível de cache vem do próprio [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

O último nível confesso que não achei, mas devo atualizar esta resposta quando encontrar.

## É necessário utilizar roteamento?

Sim, isto vem da própria arquitetura MVC, e não é oneroso em desempenho.

## Preciso sair do Entity Framework e migrar para um micro ORM como o Dapper?

Depende do que você precisa em relação a performance. Aqueles tempos mostrados na palestra ([e que estão no GitHub do Dapper até hoje](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#performance-of-select-mapping-over-500-iterations---poco-serialization)) estão desatualizados. O Entity Framework é um produto que melhora bem rapidamente e este tempo é garantidamente menor.

Se você realmente precisa de performance, eu diria que mudar para o Dapper é uma boa opção, mas esteja pronto pra fazer muita coisa manualmente, como escrever *queries* na mão ou montar seu próprio gerador de SQL.

Comment: Acho que as dicas do cache me ajudarão muito, pois essa aplicação é somente leitura e nesse contexto provavelmente terei melhor evolução gerando um cache melhor estruturado.